# Using PIP with systemctl

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pip, systemctl

I'm executing `python` script as is written on this [site](https://tecadmin.net/setup-autorun-python-script-using-systemd/) which works fine, but my `Python3` is using only packages which are installed without pip: like `sudo apt install python3-pandas`. So when I installing packages this way, I'm getting older version of `Pandas` and I'm not able to use `series.to_list()` Because I have version `22` and `to_list()` is from 24 +. When I try to update existing packages with `pip` it updates `pandas` but I'm not able to update packages installed that `sudo apt install python3-pandas` way cuz [there is not new version](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-updates-universe-amd64/8/). So I would like to execute `ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/dummy_service.py` with `pip` is that possible????

Or is there a way to write this

```py
not_null = not_null["id"].to_list() # not_null is DataFrame
```

without `to_list()`?

Comment: What OS do you use? Debian, Ubuntu, Mint…? Maybe you're not on the current OS version? My Ubuntu 20.04 has `python3-pandas` at version 0.25.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I suggest upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

you can install packages even without using pip
you can cloning pandas from https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas then run the command in the pandas directory

```
python setup.py install
```